# The Sum of double Infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

[image: Please check the question here]

could any one please tell me how can I solve this and what theorems need to be used, thanks in advance!

Comment: For absolutely convergent series, as here, rearrangement does not change the sum so you can do the (easy) sum of $j$ first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{j=2}^\infty\sum_{k=2}^\infty k^{-j} &= \sum_{k=2}^\infty\sum_{j=2}^\infty k^{-j}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k(k-1)} \,\,\,\, \text{sum of infinite geometric progression}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{k-(k-1)}{k(k-1)}\\
&= \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{k-1} - \frac{1}{k}\\
& = 1
\end{align}

Comment: Unless the final $=$ has proofs other than the one I'm about to describe, this puts the cart before the horse. We evaluate this zeta sum by converting it into the OP's question, then reversing the order of the summation, which is what the OP should try, as @lulu's comment noted.